# How do I prevent model update from changing an attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have `Account` model with attribute `role`. Roles wrote with `enum role: [:user, :admin]`. I want that if left one account with role `admin` he can't update his role to `user`. I think need to write something like this: `@account = Account.where(role: params[: role])...` and then I don't know.

**account.rb**

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  enum role: [:user, :admin]
end
```

**accounts_controller.rb**

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @accounts = Account.all
  end
  def update
    @account = Account.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to accounts_path if account.update(role: params[:role])
  end
end
```

**schema.rb**

```
create_table "accounts", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "role", default: 0
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is a [model callback](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#available-callbacks) `before_update` that acts like a validation.

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  enum role: [:user, :admin]

  before_update :insure_admin, if: -> { role == :admin && role_changed? }

  private
  def insure_admin
    errors.add(:role, "admin cannot switch to regular user")
  end
end
```

This should prevent the `account.update(role: params[:role])` from returning true but you'll probably want to handle the error in your controller, something like:

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @accounts = Account.all
  end
  def update
    @account = Account.find(params[:id])
    if account.update(role: params[:role])
      redirect_to accounts_path 
    else
      redirect_to :back, flash: account.errors.full_messages
    end
  end
end
```

You might also want to add front end form validation to not allow the form to change role if the account is already persisted.